# How do I drop a <div> element onto a canvas element in HTML5?

Tags: html, canvas, drag-and-drop

I have the following code:

```
<img draggable="true" id="company" ondragstart="drag_me(this, event)" src="company.jpg" />


<canvas id="canvas" ondrop="drop_here(this, event)" ondragover="return false" ondragenter="return false" width="800" height="750">


</canvas>
```

How do I drop the img element onto the canvas and make it appear?

Answer (score 0):

You can't draw an element to a `canvas` (though an `img` element is the exception).